# Mod_rewrite is causing contact form to not work

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, file-extension

I have a website with a contact that used to work fine.

I've narrowed it down to this mod_rewrite rule that is causing the form not to work.

```
# If client requested does not exist as a directory or a file
# then add .php to the actual filename
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

# Gets rid of the file extensions in the address bar
# If client request header contains php file extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+)\.php\ HTTP
# externally redirect to extensionless URI
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.php$ http://cacrochester.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

How can I modify this so that it will not affect the contact form on the page http://cacrochester/Contact-Us.php, but it will still remove the extensions in the address bar?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does the script not get the form data? Is the script not found?

Comment: When i comment out these mod rules and just click submit on the form, it displays the error message. When I uncomment out the rules as I have in the question and then click the submit button on the form, it looks like it just refreshes the page and does not show the error messages.

Comment: I could imagine that the 301 perm-redirect will drop the form data for (some/most?) browsers. Check other browsers or if your browser does send form data with the request on the final url.

Comment: What should I do instead of that 301 redirect? How else do you get URLs to not show the file extensions?

Comment: Well, the best way would be to correct the links. If you’re using a CMS it would be the CMSs job to do that, when generating the URLs. A simple fix would be to just tell the contact script form to point to the CORRECT url, and not the one with the file extension. You could also make an exception for that one script. Mh, AFAIK, isn’t there even a webserver for dropping file extensions? At least for apache httpd!?

Comment: What you’re doing right now is duplicating requests. On each link-click a request is sent to your webserver and the webserver responds: ask here instead (without .php). Then a second request is sent which is then answered with actual content. So that is a really bad way to do it. It’s only an option if your website already works without .php and you want to make sure old links still work but redirect to the new URLs.

Comment: I'm not using a CMS, it's just a PHP website that I created from scratch. How would I point to the CORRECT URL? I'm submitting the form to PHP_SELF so it should be pointing to the correct URL right?

Comment: so if i don't care about old links, what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Point to http://www.cacrochester.com/Contact-Us instead of http://www.cacrochester.com/Contact-Us.php And do that on every page, if you really wann do that. On each link.

Comment: The mod_rewrite you defined will only send clients to the new urls, but the links on your website all still point to the old urls. So each time a user clicks on a link hes sent to the old url, which sends him to the new one. To fix this simply fix the links to the old urls to the new ones. Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: Not sure i'm following. If i type in cacrochester.com/Contact-Us and click the form submit button, it submits to itself which is cacrochester.com/Contact-us.php. Why is that?

Comment: Because it points to the *.php* URL: `<form method="post" action="/Contact-Us.php" name="Submit">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make that form point to the URL without *.php*.

Point to `http://www.cacrochester.com/Contact-Us` instead of `http://www.cacrochester.com/Contact-Us.php`.

Comment: The form submits to itself $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

Comment: Then don’t use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` as that will add the .php again. Or drop it via sth like `substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 0, strrchr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.'))`.

Comment: Ohh I think that makes sense. I didn't know submitting a page to itself would add the .php. Can you explain where I would use your code though? Like would I put it in the $_SERVER variable or something when submitting the form?

Comment: Wherever you output the HTML `<form>` action attribute.

Comment: `echo '<form method="post" action="' . substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 0, strrchr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.')) . '" name="Submit">';` or sth like that.

Comment: PHP_SELF also includes the location-path, so if you’re not in your web root you have to remove that too. Just using *Contact-Us* may be easier, but less dynamic. `<form method="post" action="Contact-Us" name="Submit">`